# Invalid command: 'AuthLDAPAuthoritative', perhaps misspelled

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ldap, authentication, gentoo

Have apache 2.2.24 running on Gentoo server. I need apache to now authenticate through windows active directory, however, on apache service restart, I am getting this error:

> Invalid command, 'AuthzLDAPAuthoritative', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I have this in my http.conf file:

`<IfDefine AUTHNZ_LDAP>
  LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
</IfDefine>`

I have apache compiled with ldap use flag.

I have already searched around quite a bit for a solution, trying out what worked for others, however, no luck as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the `mod_ldap`. Also make sure your are actually loading those modules (you have a IfDefine in your configuration).

Comment: What I ended up doing (and now works) is loaded `mod_ldap` (as it was left out) and removed the `<IfDefine>` and `</IfDefine>` tags.